# IntelliJ 9 and Android - Filtering LogCat

Tags: android, intellij-idea, logcat

Having got fed up with Eclipse I switched my IDE over to IntelliJ and so far have not looked back (Granted only been using it for a day or so). I never used ADT drag and drop layout editing either preferring to code my XML layouts by hand or in DroidDraw, so this was never a problem.

However, one thing I do miss is the ability to filter out the LogCat display depending on the Tag I am using. I've found that you can put a Search Query into the box and that acts like a filter, but there's no way to get it into it's own tab and it's also a pain flicking back and forth between that and the full LogCat view.

The search also includes some type of drop down and I was hoping this would be filled in by what ever I searched for, but I can not get it to function at all, it's always blank. I've searched through the documentation and can not find anything.

Does anyone know how I can use this search box to act like a multiple filter choice, or if I am missing something and IntelliJ already includes this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking for a solution for this as well - quite annoying! However, this is the bug to watch and/or vote on if you want to see this addressed: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-65949

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this is not quite the answer you are looking for but as a quick workaround you could fire up a command shell run the following.

```
$ adb logcat | grep YOUR_TAG
```